# How to add custom category rule tab in form in admin side in magento 2.3.5

Tags: module, custom, magento2.3.5-p1

Hello Friends I want to add new tab in form for applying rule for specific category in magento 2.3.5.

[image: 3]

Comment: I want to create tab for assign to product tab which is displayed in screenshot and on this rule if category id selected then size chart will be displayed on that perticuar category proiducts

Comment: Your question is quite vague: we could understand your question better if you could tell us where is the screen you show in the Magento backend. Also, once you tab might be added, there is still a long way to have this tab to do anything.. not sure what you are trying to do?

Comment: My motive is to show size chart as per category id selected in magento 2